# I want to change the Text position in Oxyplot LineAnnotation

Tags: oxyplot

this code is in example

```
var lineAnnotation4 = new LineAnnotation();
        lineAnnotation4.Type = LineAnnotationType.Horizontal;
        lineAnnotation4.Y = 2;
        lineAnnotation4.Color = OxyColors.Gold;
        lineAnnotation4.MaximumX = 4;
        lineAnnotation4.Text = "Horizontal";
        plotModel1.Annotations.Add(lineAnnotation4);
```

What I was wondering.
The Text position is always below the line.
like this..
[image]

Is there a way to position text above the line?
like this..
[image]

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

<s>Try `lineAnnotation4.TextVerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top`</s>

**Edit:** 
Seems rather counter intuitive, but you actually need to specify `lineAnnotation4.TextVerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Bottom;`

Comment: I find that very intuitive. The alignment point is at the bottom of the text.